# Getting the value separated from List

Tags: string, list, dictionary, split

I would like to know how to split this list. How do I separate this:

```
'[{"cod": "starting"}, "d45aff-dffdfd-dfgssgsdf-dsg"]'
```

to:

```
{"cod": "starting"}
```

and:

```
"d45aff-dffdfd-dfgssgsdf-dsg"
```

Comment: What have you tried? In what *language*, even?

Comment: a=[{"cod": "starting"}, "d45aff-dffdfd-dfgssgsdf-dsg"]
for i in a:
    print(i)

Comment: Uh, `MyList[0]` and `MyList[1]`? That would work in most languages I know

Comment: thanks for all the comment, Sorry I didn't mention which language, It is in python. Both the answers gave me good insights. thanks all